# Moving commits back to master

Tags: git

I accidentally committed a series of commits to a branch that I didn't intend to. I had intended to put them in `master` but ended up putting them on shared branch we'll call `integ`. I'd like to find a way to remove these commits from `integ` and put them on `master`; I'd like for them never to have existed in `integ`.

Both `integ` and `master` have been shared on github. The `integ` branch is used by our CI environment.

I've read that `git rebase` is an option but from what I've read it will render the integ branch unusable going forward since it has the commits in it's history that have been re-played onto `master`. Specifically, I am referring to:

http://blog.evan.pro/a-simple-explanation-of-git-rebase

Where it says:

> DO NOT PULL, MERGE, OR REBASE FROM origin/feature/my-topic AT THIS POINT!!!
>
> Why not? Because Git simply thinks, “Oh look, origin/feature/my-topic has two commits (D and E) that we don’t have here locally in feature/my-topic. Let’s merge them in!”… That’s a problem though, because we do have those commits, but their hashes were re-written to F and G when we ran git rebase.

My questions are:

- how can I recover the state of these branches such that the 10 commits in `integ` end up on `master` and `integ` appears like it never had those commits?
- Is that possible?
- If not, how do I get back to place where I can continue on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It *is* possible to use the `integ` branch after a rebase, but it will invalidate the *currently checked out* copies that anyone has pointing to the current commit. If it is possible to get everyone to reset their `integ` branch before they make any more commits to it, then a `rebase` is an option. However it will be a royal pain for anything other than the most trivial case.

Comment: @Gareth, as it turns out that is possible. It's just me and another developer on the project. The CI work I have in integ is around testing out how best to run the build with a CI tool and I am the only working in the `integ` branch. So after rebasing I need to push all of it to github and ask the other guy to reset his copy of the branch, and then I'll be in a good place?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Your push will fail unless you add the `--force` flag because git will try to stop you removing references to the existing commits. Then after your other developer fetches (*not* pulls) your changes he will need to `git reset --hard origin/integ` while on the `integ` branch. This is where the "don't merge" warning comes in, if he pulls or otherwise merges, then git will try and merge both *his* checked out (old) branch and *your* rebased branch, leaving you with a messy tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to move the last 3 commits from `integ` to `master`.

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick integ^^
git cherry-pick integ^
git cherry-pick integ
git checkout integ
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Comment: I was able to cherry-pick my commits back to `master` and then reset `integ` to the commit the preceeded the commits that I cherry-picked. I was able to push the changes on `integ` to Github using `push --force` and everything is working. Thus, @TheBuzzSaw suggestion worked for me. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: TheBuzzSaw might as well be the git god.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "delete" something from git's history. You can `revert` the commits by using

```
git revert HEAD~n
```

or

```
git revert $SHA1_HASH
```

After doing this, you have to create patches from the commits and manually apply them on your master branch or use `git cherry-pick`, which is essentially the same (thanks to sleske for metioning!)

Comment: Nitpick: you *can* delete something from history using `git rebase` (or `git reset --hard`), combined with `git push -f`. However, this is not advisable in this case, so this is the right solution.

Comment: Yet another way of copying the commits from integ to master would be to use `git rebase --onto`. See http://pivotallabs.com/git-rebase-onto/ (Please note that this will not remove the commits from integ, it is just advice on how to copy them to master)

Comment: Also, the "you can merge your branch into master" is wrong - this will not work, precisely because the commits were reverted. To copy the commits to master, you need to create&apply patches, or use use `git cherry-pick` (which does esssentially the same thing).

Comment: Thanks @akluth! So when I do a  `git revert HASH`, this will reset the branch state but leave the changes in my local code and then I can create a patch from that and apply it to master, is that right?

Comment: But he reverted the commits from the `integ` branch and not his feature branch, so he can merge the commits from his feature branch into master.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn: No, using rebase is not a good idea here (as explained above), since the commits were already shared.

Comment: @Jon: You simply merged your feature branch into `integ` instead of master, didn't you? So then you simply revert the changes in the `integ` branch and then merge your feature branch into master.

Comment: @akluth: No, he writes he commited to `integ` instead of to `master`. They *may* have come from a feature branch of course, in which case you'd be right.

Comment: @slesk I am aware of the fact that rebase is not a good solution to the problem of the commits on integ. I was just trying to suggest a way to solve the, admittedly much simpler, part of the problem concerning reproducing the commits on master.

Comment: @akluth - no I have not merged anything. The `integ` branch was created from `master`, to be clear. It would be my preference to leave `integ` as a branch because it's how we're running or CI for the moment (we're still trying to sort how best to work our CI with Git due to our build being somewhat involved).

Comment: @sleske: Ah, I overread this, I think it's time to go to bed :-)

Comment: @Jon: Little tip: consider using a workflow like http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ - we're using this across our projects (and with Mercurial either)

Comment: @akluth, Thanks for the tip, I'll read that in detail later. Going back to your original post, I've been reading the book "Pragmatic Guide to Git" by Travis Swicegood. On page 112 it talks about `rebase` being capable of removing commits from history and the index, so this is why I thought it might be possible to remove the commits altogether. I am looking to do this in whatever is least painful or, conversely, the mostly correct way to avoid future pain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the commits from "integ" to "master" you should make a merge. Try to do this first to ensure doesn't lose changes.
If nobody has made a commit over the master is going to be a fast forward merge.
Then you can worry about how are you going to delete those commits from integ (I don't know how).